# Working of EggPlant Mobile in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, eggplant

I want to know the working of EggPlant Mobile for iOS. All i know is that Eggplant functional application creates Test Scripts and execute those Tests on Mobile. Now i want to know that how that execution works at iOS end. My guess is that they are using GSEvent for simulating touch event on iOS 6. Am i correct?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Eggplant Mobile (as well as the primary product Eggplant Functional) uses a VNC server on device under test (iOS or Android) to interact with it.  Currently, I believe that their VNC server application for iOS only works for iOS 6, iOS 7 must have added new restrictions as their application must be compiled into the source code of the iOS application being tested for it to work.

Source: http://docs.testplant.com/?q=content/creating-connection-eggon (see the first picture)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have tried to figure out but it is still unknown that how they are handling system wide touch on iPhone in iOS 7. As there are restrictions on using private API's also in iOS 7.

Comment: Hi iOS Dev do you get any solution for this?